# "Pure" Map-reduce shuffle in pyspark df

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

assuming i have some pyspark df, f.e:

```
Key | Value
0   | "a"
2   | "c"
0   | "b"
1   | "z"
```

I want to perform map-reduce-like shuffle method - 
i.e. I want to group rows on partitions by keys.
I believe **`df.rdd.groupByKey()`** does that, but it changes `df` structure

- it returns list of tuples with list as value (grouped key).

How can I perform "pure" shuffle function - Move my objects to specific partition, but do not change anything in `df` appearance / structure?

So the output would be the same but partitioning would be different. For example - we start with 2 paritions:

```
(0,"a")
(1,"c")
(1,"d")
```

and

```
(1,"d")
(0:"e")
(1,"w")
```

as a result we get two partitions:

```
(0,"a")
(0:"e")
```

and

```
(1,"d")
(1,"c")
(1,"d")
(1,"w")
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output? What's the point of having shuffle but not changing structure? Or do you meant sorting?

Comment: I add a example

Comment: And what do you want to do with those partitions? More calculation or save them separately?

Comment: More calculations, i want to sort them within partitions (that's part of TeraSort algorithm) and then perform some other calculations.

Comment: then you can use [`rdd.mapPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions.html)